# why is the outlook 365 business (version 1904, build 11601.20230) deleted items folder not purging deleted items

Tags: microsoft-outlook

My deleted items folder is not purging any more - when i click on the recover deleted items button to pull up that folder - then choose "purge selected items" and "select all" then "OK" - the folder goes through the motions appearing to count down and delete the items. But when I re-open the folder, which should be empty as it has been in the past after this operation, the same items are in the folder.

I am the only user of this account. There are no other admins or users.

What changed and when are they going to fix it?

Edit:
Who is providing your email service? Is it Office 365 as well? - Yes, via Microsoft Exchange - all through a GoDaddy account

Have you checked for sync conflicts? - No, don't know how. I've never had a sync issue before. This appears to be a recent software change.

Have you tried creating a new profile? - No

How many items are in there? - I don't know exactly probably 700 or 800 emails

Have you waited a day to see if it will clear out? - Yes, I have done this operation multiple times. Waited a day or two between times. Tried it from both my home computer and the one in my office.  The only thing I haven't done is to go online and try deleting from the actual Office 365 online account.  Which I shouldn't have to do.

Please edit your question and provide these details. - done

Comment: Who is providing your email service? Is it Office 365 as well? Have you checked for [sync conflicts](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjF5tCL98TiAhWhwFkKHdtoCWYQzPwBegQIARAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.howtogeek.com%2F377695%2Fview-and-delete-sync-issues-in-outlook%2F&psig=AOvVaw2Chj02VbgcQYsbF44SQ98E&ust=1559363295360898)? Have you tried creating a new profile? How many items are in there? Have you waited a day to see if it will clear out? Please [edit] your question and provide these details.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue that Exchange Online account can’t purge or restore items in Outlook client. This is due to that a recent code change may be causing MAPI calls to fail, preventing some users from restoring or purging items in the RDI folder.

This information was published on Office 365 Admin Center. Microsoft is aware of this issue and investigating into it. We may wait for an update.